# Parent term suggestion on entering the child term in term reference field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I have a term reference field which has the widget `Autocomplete term widget (tagging)`.
I want the functionality like, when a user type a child term in that autocomplete field, the system should return a suggestion of the parent term that did you mean `[parent term]`.

Suppose `A` is a parent term and its child term is `B`. So when a user type `B` in the field, it should show a suggestion of did you mean `A`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to override the taxonomy autocomplete path. Here's what you will need:

1. `hook_menu_alter()` implementation, so your custom module takes over the taxonomy autocomplete suggestions. See `hook_menu()` implementation, specifically `$item['taxonomy/autocomplete']` item in `/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module` for more information.
2. You'll need to re-create the core `taxonomy_autocomplete()` function, which is in `/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.pages.inc`.
3. You'll have to perform a check and see for which vocabulary you need to show suggestions:

   - If it's the vocabulary where you want to have child -> parent functionality, add the code for fetching the parent term and provide additional suggestions.
   - If it's some other vocabulary, make sure you return the same output as the core function would.

You'll need to add this in a custom module.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // This will re-route this path to your custom module, so you can have any
  // additional logic.
  $items['taxonomy/autocomplete']['page callback'] = 'YOUR_MODULE_taxonomy_autocomplete';
}

function YOUR_MODULE_taxonomy_autocomplete($field_name = '', $tags_typed = '') {
  // Copy the content of taxonomy_autocomplete() function here, and add necessary
  // modifications at the end of it.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm already here :-). But doesn't know what to do hear :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for computing the parent.

```
function demo_pane_taxonomy_autocomplete($field_name = '', $tags_typed = '') {
  // Copy the content of taxonomy_autocomplete() function here, and add necessary
  // modifications at the end of it.

  // If the request has a '/' in the search text, then the menu system will have
  // split it into multiple arguments, recover the intended $tags_typed.
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Shift off the $field_name argument.
  array_shift($args);
  $tags_typed = implode('/', $args);

  // Make sure the field exists and is a taxonomy field.
  if (!($field = field_info_field($field_name)) || $field['type'] !== 'taxonomy_term_reference') {
    // Error string. The JavaScript handler will realize this is not JSON and
    // will display it as debugging information.
    print t('Taxonomy field @field_name not found.', array('@field_name' => $field_name));
    exit;
  }

  // The user enters a comma-separated list of tags. We only autocomplete the last tag.
  $tags_typed = drupal_explode_tags($tags_typed);
  $tag_last = drupal_strtolower(array_pop($tags_typed));

  $term_matches = array();
  if ($tag_last != '') {

    // Part of the criteria for the query come from the field's own settings.
    $vids = array();
    $vocabularies = taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names();
    foreach ($field['settings']['allowed_values'] as $tree) {
      $vids[] = $vocabularies[$tree['vocabulary']]->vid;
    }

    $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
    $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 't.tid=h.tid');
    $query->addTag('translatable');
    $query->addTag('term_access');

    // Do not select already entered terms.
    if (!empty($tags_typed)) {
      $query->condition('t.name', $tags_typed, 'NOT IN');
    }
    // Select rows that match by term name.
    $tags_return = $query
      ->fields('t', array('tid', 'name'))
      ->fields('h', array('parent'))
      ->condition('t.vid', $vids)
      ->condition('t.name', '%' . db_like($tag_last) . '%', 'LIKE')
      ->range(0, 10)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();

      $tags_new_return = array();
      $parent_array = array();

      foreach($tags_return as $tag_key=>$tag_val) {
        if($tag_val->parent != 0) {
          $parent_array[] = $tag_val->parent;
        }
      }

      unset($tags_return);
    $query_1 = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't1');
    $query_1->addTag('translatable');
    $query_1->addTag('term_access');

    // Do not select already entered terms.
    if (!empty($tags_typed)) {
      $query->condition('t.name', $tags_typed, 'NOT IN');
    }
    // Select rows that match by term name.
    $tags_return = $query_1
      ->fields('t1', array('tid', 'name'))
      ->condition('t1.tid', $parent_array, 'IN')
      ->range(0, 10)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAllKeyed();

    $prefix = count($tags_typed) ? drupal_implode_tags($tags_typed) . ', ' : '';

    foreach ($tags_return as $tid => $name) {
      $n = $name;
      // Term names containing commas or quotes must be wrapped in quotes.
      if (strpos($name, ',') !== FALSE || strpos($name, '"') !== FALSE) {
        $n = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
      }
      $term_matches[$prefix . $n] = check_plain($name);
    }
  }

  drupal_json_output($term_matches);
}
```

Be sure to apply the check of field_name in it, I have not applied that check.